# Setting job tags for Neptune

Tags: tags, neptune

Recently I started using Neptune (via [Neptune Go](https://go.neptune.deepsense.io/)) and want to have a well-organised history of experiments. How to set tags to a given experiment? (Do I do it before running it, or after?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are four ways to set tags to your experiment:

1. In the `run/enqueue/exec` command, i.e:

`neptune run --tags tag1 tag2 tag3 tag4`

2. In the configuration file:

`tags: [tag1, tag2, tag3, tag4]`

3. In your code:

`ctx.job.tags.append('new-tag')`

4. In the Web UI. In the experiment dashboard you have to click on "Job Properties" in the top left corner of the screen. Side panel will appear where you can modify job properties.

So you can change tags of your experiment in every phase of your experiment execution.

Sources:

- http://neptune.deepsense.io/versions/latest/reference-guides/cli.html#tags
- http://neptune.deepsense.io/versions/latest/reference-guides/job-and-experiment.html#tags